# Unable to move GameObject?

Tags: unity, c#

This simulates a GameObject swinging between two positions.

I am unable to manually move a GameObject on the Y axis using the Unity editor (in scene view) when the following script is attached and running, it's like a solid animation:

```
Vector3 min, max;

void Update()
{
    min = wall1.position + new Vector3(4,0,0); 
    max = wall2.position - new Vector3(4,0,0);

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (min, max, (Mathf.Sin(2 * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to think about how you want to combine movement from multiple sources. The rule you're using now is "sine wave between the two walls always wins - all other movement is ignored." But you could have all kinds of other rules, like "sine wave wins on the x axis, but other sources can move the object on the y & z axes" or "other sources apply an offset to the sine wave, allowing it to get closer or further from its min & max" or many other options. What rule would you *like* the object to follow?

Comment: @DMGregory Exactly, that's what I need: "sine wave wins on the x axis, but other sources can move the object on the y & z axes" How do we do it properly with code?

Comment: @DMGregory The current answer does not solve the problem. I need a proper revised version of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a `Vector3` to `transform.position`, you assign all three axises. To assign only X axis, you need to do this:

```
var oldPos = transform.position;
var newPos = new Vector3(__newXValue__, oldPos.y, oldPos.z);
transform.position = newPos;
```

Change `__newXValue__` with what you want, and this code will only change x axis and other axises will not get effected by this code.

**Note:** Do not split these lines to different methods that will run on different frames, the integrity must remain intact. The reason for this is, if transform gets updated from any other source in between you get the old position and assign new position, your GameObject will teleport.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, I don't see how I can implement this logic with my own code. Can you give an answer with the code that I provided?

Comment: @Kosde Replace `__newXValue__` with `Vector3.Lerp` method's X return.

Comment: It does not work, I'm getting errors. Here's the code that I made: `var oldPos = transform.position;
  var newPos = new Vector3(Vector3.Lerp (min, max, (Mathf.Sin(2 * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f), oldPos.y, oldPos.z);
  transform.position = newPos;`

Comment: `var oldPos = transform.position; var newPos = new Vector3((Vector3.Lerp (min, max, (Mathf.Sin(2 * Time.time) + 1.0f) / 2.0f)).x, oldPos.y, oldPos.z); transform.position = newPos;`

Comment: Thank you my friend, it works now. I love correct straightforward answers.

Comment: @Kosde Also note that, assigning every step to a different variable is a good practice overall. So consider not inlining that Lerp function, instead assign it to a Vector3 and use that local variable instead. And don't rely on `var` keyword very much, I used it here just for the sake of writing a fast answer.

Comment: @SamedTank there's no particular harm in using `var`. It's still strongly & statically typed, it's just syntactic sugar that asks the compiler to infer the type at compile time. So it doesn't incur any extra runtime cost, and a good IDE will still be able to give you hints as normal. In my experience, using `var` reduces the amount of bookkeeping code changes I need to do when refactoring part of my code to use a different type that still supports the same operations.

Comment: @DMGregory Just to clarify, I am not against the use of var keyword, I myself use it very often. My suggestion only stands for efficiency of programmer, not the program itself. It is always good to actually see what type the variable is, without hovering mouse over the var keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When your game is running, the Update() function update the GameObject's position every frame so you can't move it (actually you can move it but the update position it so fast that the move do not work).

You can try this: make this GameObject another GameObject's child in hierachy, and move the parent GameObject, it will work the way you want it.

Comment: This simply does not work.

Comment: As DMGregory well said:  That's what I need: "sine wave wins on the x axis, but other sources can move the object on the y & z axes" How do we do it properly with code?
     
Your answer does not solve the problem. I need a proper revised version of my code.

Comment: This should work, if you assign localPosition only on child.